# By entering values into table, command line does not work

Tags: postgresql, postgis, psql

I am using a book call PostGIS in action, by Regine Obe and Leo Hsu.
They have the following example to create an schema, a table and populate it with values. The problem as you can see is that after entering the values of id and franchise, the command line does not respond to display the information entered. It contains the `'`, and does not respond to the command \dt. How is the correct way to enter information in a multiline command execution in postgis as stated in my example?

```
CREATE SCHEMA ch01; 
CREATE TABLE
postgis_in_action=# INSERT INTO ch01.franchises(id, franchise)
postgis_in_action-# VALUES
postgis_in_action-# ('BKG', 'Burger King'), ('CJR', 'Carl''s Jr'), 
postgis_in_action-# ('HDE', 'Hardee'), ('INO', 'In-N-Out'),
postgis_in_action-# ('JIB', 'Jack in the Box'), ('KFC', 'Kentucky Fried Chicken'),
postgis_in_action-# ('MCD', 'McDonald'), ('PZH', 'Pizza Hut'), 
postgis_in_action-# ('TCB', 'Taco Bell'), ('WDY', 'Wendy's'); 
postgis_in_action'# \dt
postgis_in_action'#
```

Comment: `'Wendy's'` should be `'Wendy''s'`  (the same way you did it for `'Carl''s Jr'`)

Comment: For future use, the hint was here: ```postgis_in_action'# ``` Note the ' indicating an open quote.